# Unable to run kafka streaming with pyspark from jupyter notebook

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to receive kafka stream of message from pyspark application in jupyter notebook.I have also added dependent kafka spark package to the SPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS in the jupyter notebook itself but I am getting the following error when I am trying to listen to kafka messages

```
Spark Streaming's Kafka libraries not found in class path. Try one of the 
following
1. Include the Kafka library and its dependencies with in the
 spark-submit command as
$ bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0- 
8:2.3.1 
...
2. Download the JAR of the artifact from Maven Central 
http://search.maven.org/,
Group Id = org.apache.spark, Artifact Id = spark-streaming-kafka-0-8- 
assembly, 
Version = 2.3.1.
Then, include the jar in the spark-submit command as
$ bin/spark-submit --jars <spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly.jar>
```

My code is:

```
import os  
  os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark- 
  streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.2 pyspark-shell'
  from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
  from pyspark import SparkContext
  from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
  sc=SparkContext(master='--local[2]')
  ssc=StreamingContext(sc,3)
  kk=KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc,'localhost:2181','demo',{'hello':'1'})
```

Comment: ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 985, in send_command
    response = connection.send_command(command)
  File "C:\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1164, in send_command
    "Error while receiving", e, proto.ERROR_ON_RECEIVE)
Py4JNetworkError: Error while receiving

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to connect Spark to Zookeeper in order to read from Kafka?

Comment: Getting the same error. No solution yet on it.
@ParakhAgarwal please let me know if you have a solution